# Common user to modify files owned by 'other' users

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, files

I would like to understand how to use the permission system in CentOS to achieve the following:

The system has the following users:

```
user1
user2
user3
```

And the following directory structure..

```
/dir1
  /dir2
  /dir3
```

User 2 executes files within dir 2, so it needs to be able to write to them
User 3 executes files within dir 3, so it needs to be able to write to them

User 2 should **not** be able to modify dir3
User 3 should **not** be able to modify dir2

The problem comes when i need User 1 to be able to modify dir2 and dir3..

Comment: Just bind mount the dirs r/o for the users that cant modify them and mount them r/w for those that can.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know
change the ownership of file
chown root:user1 dir1
chown root:user2 dir2
chown root:user3 dir3

change the permission of the file
chmod 764 user1
chmod 764 user2
chmod 764 user3

Hope you have the root permission
If not then use sudo

you need to add the users in one group say for example group1
groupadd group1
useradd -G group1 user1
useradd -G group1 user2
useradd -G group1 user3

now you can do setfacl ACL for the user1 for use dir1 dir2 & dir3
setfacl -R g:group1:rwx

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this without fancy ACLs would be to have two separate groups: `group2` and `group3`.

- The users `user1` and `user2` should be members of `group2` and `user1` and `user3` should be members of `group3`.
- Then `dir2` should be owned by `group2` and `dir3` should be owned by `dir3`.
- Both `dir2` and `dir3` should be readable and writable by their group owner and have the [setgid bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories) set so that new files are created with group ownership of the containing directory instead of the primary group of the creating user.
- Finally, `dir1` should be traversable (but not readable) by everyone.

In commands:

```
groupadd group2
groupadd group3
usermod -a -G group2 user1
usermod -a -G group2 user2
usermod -a -G group3 user1
usermod -a -G group3 user3

chmod 0711 dir1

chgrp group2 dir1/dir2
chmod 2770 dir1/dir2

chgrp group3 dir1/dir3
chmod 2770 dir1/dir3
```